# Does boost chrono process_real_cpu_clock provide info in ticks?

Tags: c++, boost, c++-chrono

Does boost chrono process_real_cpu_clock provide info in ticks or nanoseconds or different on windows and linux?

Comment: What prevented you from performing some research? The answer is trivially found in the first Google result for `process_real_cpu_clock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for [`process_real_cpu_clock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.other_clocks.process_cpu_clocks_hpp.process_real_cpu_clock)<sup>†</sup> clearly identifies the member type `duration` as being in nanoseconds.

(Note that this does *not* in itself guarantee nanosecond precision or accuracy, only nanosecond units.)

<sup><sup>†</sup> You did not specify what version you are using, so I have assumed 1.55.0 for the link.</sup>